# Call codebehind function in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to do a very simple task. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I need to pass some values to code behind method, do some calculations there and then return the result. I started with a test method. There are many examples on web. But nothing working for me.

Please see my default page code below:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication7._Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          var loc = window.location.href;
          $("#btnClick").click(function (event) {
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: loc + "/GetMessage",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

               })
               .success(function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);

                })
                .error(function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                });
           });
      });

  </script>

   <input id="btnClick" type="button" value="button" />


</asp:Content>
```

The jquery has been referenced in master page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

codebehind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetMessage()
    {
        return "test";
    }
```

I do get "Undefined" error. When I change the .success and .error function like below

```
           .success(function () {
                alert("S");

            })
            .error(function () {
                alert("E");
            });
```

It shows "S". My understanding is that it finds the code behind method. But the 'response' is undefined. Does it mean the code behind method is not returning the data in json format?

Comment: specify the `dataType` header for your return type.

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery twice? Use either `jquery-2.1.0.js` or `jquery-2.1.0.min.js`. I would recommend `.min` version

Comment: @Andrew Still getting the same error.

Comment: @Satpal Removed one reference, does not make any difference.

Comment: Check your ScriptManager. Set the "EnablePageMethods" property to true. Also, try setting `return "test"` to `return "{\"test\":\"test\"}";`

Comment: @MightyLampshade Scriptmanager is in master page ..<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"> and I changed the code behind return string. Still getting the same error. I even started a new project. Still does not work.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried setting the datatype to json? Then in your `.success`, try this `var mydata = $.parseJSON(response);alert(mydata.test);`

Comment: @MightyLampshade, This too does not work. I think the 'response' is either null or incorrect format. I used jquery to retrieve autocomplete datasource, but through webservice.

Comment: @MightyLampshade, Please see my autocomplete datasource:                            data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",                 success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },

Comment: I just tried with j query 1.7.1. I cannot go back to old version.

Comment: The higher version is working if I build the project with vs2012. But in vs2013 even the lower version is not working. Other than bootstrap.js everything else is identical. Strange.

Comment: That is strange. I haven't used VS2013 myself so I can't really give you an explanation. Is the jQuery.js file being included in the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue by commenting out the code in App_Start. Murali's suggestion help me to find out the actual issue. The exception was 'authentication failed'.
    //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `.d` and check with console

```
.success(function (response) {
  console.log(response); //  in firefox/chrome
  alert(response);

})
```

Check the firebug console for the JSON output. Below is sample screenshot

[image]

Comment: Still throwing exception. Only difference in format. It now shows [Object] [Object].

Comment: @Anup, check the firefox/chrome network/console and see what is the response from server

Comment: @Anup, I was asking you to check the response data , i.e json output. Not the headers

Comment: @Anup, check the updated answer for firebug console help

Comment: I cannot see jason in firebug. I have contentType: "application/json; in request. Could you please advise?

Comment: I just tried with j query 1.7.1. I cannot go back to old version.

Comment: The higher version is working if I build the project with vs2012. But in vs2013 even the lower version is not working. Other than bootstrap.js everything else is identical. Strange.

Comment: jason                                                          Message                                             "Authentication failed."
StackTrace null
ExceptionType "System.InvalidOperationException"

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one.

```
       .success(function (data) {
            alert(data);

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

First use only a single version(`minified or unminified`) of `jquery` and use `dataType:'json'` like,

```
$("#btnClick").click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: loc + "/GetMessage",
        dataType: 'json', // for json data, which is parsed
        success:function (response) {//combining success and error callback in ajax
            console.log(response);
        },
        error:function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: I am getting the same Error: [object Object].

Comment: This is because you are not responding your data as json, its simply a string, change this `return "test";` to `return '{"d":"test"}';`

Comment: This will not run as valid c# code.I tried "{\"d\":\"test\"}"; All the examples I have seen on the web is exactly like this. Is there any major changes in recent JQuery versions?

Answer (score 0):

You´ll need to remove the attribute runat="server" in the following line:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

Because that says, that the javascript code runs at the server and not at the client/browser, as excepted. Changing this should fix all your problems.